# Access to Redis Cluster via Single Endpoint

Tags: spring, redis, jedis, redis-cluster

I have a application  using Redis. This system implemented with java spring used jedis package for connection to the redis with the configuration as follow

```
jedis.pool.host=redisServer-IP
```

so the application connect to redis server  on the **redisServer-IP** and works fine but, for the lack of memory on a single server and  and HA capability I need to use a redis cluster I used docker compose to create a redis cluster using the [here](https://bpaulino.com/entries/how-to-use-redis-cluster-for-caching).
Also redis cluster working fine with three masters and three replicas.
I just need to understand, the Redis Cluster can work with the single endpoint,  because I can only set single endpoint in the above jedis.pool.host configuration, or I need to have a proxy to deal with  the redis cluster ?

**NOTE: I can not make any changes in my application**